# My side bar menu conflicts with my tableview commitEditingStyle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem with my tableview .

I have a Mainviewcontroller with a side bar menu . 
In my viewdidload I have this :

```
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

But in this view I also have a tableview with method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

But to delete my object, de right slide doesn't work. It works after 10 times, 5 times, 3 times, 12 times. It is very random . When I delete `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];` it works correctly ?

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: I believe the problem is due to the pan gesture of the UITableView and the one for SWRevealViewController conflicting. I had a similar issue and just added a button to each cell, that when tapped, deletes that row.

Comment: It's a solution but I already have a button that make other action. I think they are an other solution . But I have any idea how to resolve that

Comment: if you have any idea about resolve this problem than please replay me also because i have also this problem and i also want both pan gesture and cell editing.